# List index out of range on member update AuditLogAction discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I want code logger bot but I have problem on member update event.
I want mention person who added role and person who got role.

So I coded This:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before , after):
    guild = after.guild
    logs = await guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.member_update).flatten()
    logs = logs[0]
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        newrole = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
        await channel.send("Role Added By: "+logs.user.mention+"\nRole Added To: "+logs.target.mention+"\nRole: "+newrole)
```

But I got this error:

```
in on_member_update
    logs = logs[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I did not face problem in coding log for other events like: on member ban and...
But in this case I got that problem.
What should I do?I did not find any solution.

Comment: Does your bot have the `view_audit_log` permission?

Comment: @itzFlubby It has Administrator permission

Comment: If no errors occur at `logs = await guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.member_update).flatten()` then the audit log is fetched successfully. The `list index out of range` exception would tell you that there simply are no entries, which fit your filter. Are you **sure** that these exist?`

Comment: @itzFlubby I test my bot in other server on discord now and result was different!
I did not face with any errors but logs.user and logs.target was not correct!
`logs.user` was not person who added role and it mentions other user!. `logs.target` either!!!!